# Какой паттерн проектирования можно применить?

Tags: java, android, view, шаблоны-проектирования

Имеется вьюшка типа `RootView`, содержащая в себе другие вьюшки типа `Item`, довольно гибко кастомизируемые. Вьюшки типа `Item` динамически создаются и удаляются внутри вьюшки `RootView` по событиям (допустим по клику на них). В вьюшках типа `Item` содержатся компоненты, которые при динамическом создании необходимо конфигурировать, а также обеспечить получение данных (`getVaue`) из `Item` в `RootView` и их назначение (`setValue`), так как `RootView` может работать в двух режимах (`show` и `edit`).

Вопрос касается конкретно создания объектов типа `Item`. Сама их конфигурация определяется в `RootView`. На данный момент конфигурация и слушатели интерфейсов передаются в конструктор `Item`. Хотелось бы узнать, какой паттерн можно применить в данной ситуации? Необходим какой-то конфигуратор, декоратор или что-то на подобии того?

Comment: перед тем как чтото применять, надо понять какую проблему нужно решить. я в вопросе проблему не увидел, что то куда то передается и конфигурируется.